# How to prove it when f(x,y) is not given

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that $$\int_0^{4a}\int_{\frac{x^2}{4a}}^{2\sqrt{ax}}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^{4a}\int_{\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{2\sqrt{ay}}f(x,y)dydx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curves $y=\frac{x^2}{4a}$ and $y=2\sqrt{ax}$ intersect at $(4a,4a)$

Now, $0\le x\le4a \implies \color{blue}{0\le y\le4a}$ in the required region.

[image]

The given equations can be rewritten as,

$y = \frac{x^2}{4a} \to \color{blue}{x = 2\sqrt{ay}}$
$y = 2\sqrt{ax} \to \color{blue}{x = \frac{y^2}{4a}}$

Just substitute these limits for $x$ and $y$ and interchange the order of integration.